# Is it possible to defer the execution of thrown errors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I'm using `try/catch` blocks in many places to manage error flow. However, lately I figured out that "immediately throwing error upon an unwanted action" was a wrong decision. I need to accumulate *all* of errors and only then throw one or more exception?.

Is there a possible way to implement this,  without fully refactor my code by converting every `throw new Error...` to a deferred error handling function?

Comment: You could have some array that each catch, you push the error into. At the end, check the length of this array, and handle them however you wish. Kind of hard to help with no code available, so this is a guess haha

Comment: try following for quick hack. Monkey patch the `console.error` or add a event listener `window.addEventListener("error", handleError, true)` to capture all errors globally